# SQL AlwaysOn Data Sync

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We are in the planning phase to implement AlwaysOn Availability Groups. What is the best practice to setup the file share for data synchronization? Network path or local machine (creating a share on one of the SQL servers)? If we put it on a file server, Would there be a performance hit reading the data from the file server? If we put it on one of the SQL server, what will happen if we lost that server? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best practice to setup the file share for data synchronization? Network path or local machine

You have to really read up on AlwaysON. AlwaysON [**ships only log blocks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-always-onwhen-is-my-secondary-failover-ready). So there is no fileshare concept.

On the windows cluster, you can set a witness as fileshare. So, the witness (disk or fileshare) is **not AlwaysOn** specific. It is required by the Windows Server Failover Cluster to maintain quorum during node failures. Check [What exactly is a File Share Witness and when should I use one?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301130310/http://blogs.technet.com:80/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/06/27/clustering-what-exactly-is-a-file-share-witness-and-when-should-i-use-one.aspx)

Some good references to get you started :

- [AlwaysOn Availability Groups Quiz and FAQ [Video]](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/02/alwayson-availability-groups-faq/) - by Brent Ozar.
- [Overview of AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Creation and Configuration of Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/creation-and-configuration-of-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Also the Ozar crew just posted some free videos on clustering and AGs here: http://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/events/

Comment: So, it doesn't matter if the data sync share is on file server or one of the SQL server? I understand the witness as fileshare and that is where we are heading but where to put the data sync is the question. Thank you Kin & Aaron!

Comment: @db7 Please read the document .. all data is in memory .. **NO SHARE** is required.

Comment: @db7 What "data sync" are you talking about that has to go to a file share? Do you mean the initial location where a full backup + log has to go to initiate the secondary?

Comment: Correct, the initial data synchronization preference by specifying a shared network location accessible by all replicas...

Comment: @db7 Well, after initial setup, that location isn't really used unless you continue to back up logs there (and obviously a shared network location accessible from all replicas is a good idea, since any replica may need to back up to that location). Availability Groups isn't log shipping, so if that location is slow, it wouldn't affect the AG itself, it would just mean your log backups would be slow. Similarly if the location went down, it wouldn't stop the AG from working, it would just mean the log backup jobs would start failing.

Comment: @db7 you are confusing by **not** using proper terminology. The share you are talking is only used for initial backup and then using the same backup to restore on the replica `WITH NORECOVERY`. Then all the synchronization (log blocks) happens in memory.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was used for "initial" setup only. That makes more sense now. I don't need to take log backup as I'm using 3rd party software. Great, many thanks to Aaron & Kin. Much appreciated!